# Max Number of FileConnections

Tags: api, file, java-me

Is there a theoretical or practical limit to the maximum number of open FileConnections?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on the concrete device. There is no restrinctions in specs.

Comment: Didn't find any restrictions myself either. It's sad working with big files (~few MBs) is very slow. Even on more expensive devices. Very limited (and somewhat buggy) environment. Thanks!

Comment: I think you should not think about this restrictions. If it really exist you just stop to split files.

Comment: Ok, thanks! By the way, I am not splitting anything, just there are different pieces of info in different files, that's all. Thanks!